# Optimal Approximation of Convex Sets

Tags: functional-analysis

$ \forall z\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$,let

(a) $\|z\|_{1}=|x|+|y|$;
(b) $\|z\|_{2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$;
(c) $\|z\|_{3}=\sqrt[3]{|x|^3+|y|^3}$.

1.Prove that $\|\cdot\|_{k}(1,2,3)$ are norms in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

2.Draw unit spherical figures in each $(\mathbb{R}^{2},\|\cdot\|_{k})(k=1,2,3)$

3.Let $e_{1}=(1/2,1),e_{2}=(1/2,-1/2)$,find $a\in \mathbb{R}$s.t.
$$\|e_{2}-ae_{1}\|_{1}=\min\{\|e_{2}-\lambda e_{1}\|_{k}:\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\},$$
and ask whether such a is unique? Please give a geometric interpretation of the result.

This question is adapted from Exercise 1.4.9 in Zhang Gongqing's functional analysis textbook.

I know that a here is unique and is -1/2, but I don't know how to explain the uniqueness of a from a geometric point of view. I think this may be related to the second question. This problem has troubled me for a long time.

Comment: Are you sure there are squares, not cubes, under the cubic root in (c)?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, and I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw $\boldsymbol e_1$ and $\boldsymbol e_2$ in the plane. Then $\boldsymbol e_2 - a \boldsymbol e_1$ is a vector pointing to $\boldsymbol e_2$ from any point on the line spanned by $\boldsymbol e_1$ (denoted by $\mathbb R \boldsymbol e_1$). You want to minimize the $l_1$-norm of this vector. Equivalently, you can draw an $l_1$-circle centered at $\boldsymbol e_2$, increase its radius, and stop as soon as the circle touches the line $\mathbb R \boldsymbol e_1$. This gives you the unique minimizer at $a = -1/2$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t understand, but the uniqueness of the best approximation element is guaranteed due to strict convexity, the space $(\mathbb{R}^{2},\|\cdot\|_{1})$ is not strictly convex, how to guarantee the uniqueness of a?

Comment: @uynaix Simply put, because $\boldsymbol e_1$ does not have a 45 degree angle with x-axis. You can see this from a sketch.